# Objective C - ViewController's functions aren't working when VC is called from button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, presentviewcontroller

I have problem with one of the buttons on my Alert View.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {

        UIAlertView *welcomeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome!" message:@"This is your first run of Energy Calculator, please select Your default settings first!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Go to settings", nil];
        [welcomeAlert show];

        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
    }



    [super viewDidLoad];
}    
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)welcomeAlert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

        if (buttonIndex == [welcomeAlert cancelButtonIndex]) {

            [welcomeAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
            NSLog(@"przycisk 1");

        } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            SettingsVC *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SVC"];
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];


             }
        }
```

When I am using "normal" switch button on my First ViewController, every function on Second Viewcontroler works flawless (i.e. multilpying two values, or even "back" button with simple "dismiss view controller" method).
Mark that, that this "normal" swith button has method "present 2nd view controller modally"

But when I use  "Go to settings" button on UIAlertView, none of above functions work. I think the part of the problem is that 2nd view controller is non-modally presented, unlike with help of "normal" switch button.
Any ideas for solutions?

Comment: I would advise you to use UIAlertController since UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8.0
Can you clarify a bit how you set up your view controllers and what you are trying to achieve exaclty ? it is not very clear.

Comment: I would like to present my second View Modally (!) by clicking button in alert view, because when I present it through "PresentViewController", none of the methods on second View will work.

Comment: So when your are presenting your view controller, it is actually showing but it’s not functional ?

Comment: Yes, is not functional at all. I cannot use "back" button, none of my actions work.

Comment: And BTW, i know that UIAlerView will be deprecated, but i don't need to develop this app after i finish with it.

Comment: It is already deprecated since iOS 8.0.
Anw, how are did you set your view controllers ? Are you using a Navigation Controller ? is there a segue from VC1 to VC2 ? if there is you don’t need to instantiate a new vc, all you need is to call performseguewithidentifier method, and to go back you create an unwind segue.
I can’t really help you unless you make it clearer.

Comment: Try moving a call to `[super viewDidLoad]` as a first line in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see you set delegate for welcomeAlert, so how the function alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: is called?

Comment: There is segue from VC1 to VC2 but it is used to send values.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Your answers, I decided to try using segue that has been normally used to send data between controllers. I was not aware of that I can use segue once more.

There are my changes - commented lines are all things I tried.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)welcomeAlert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == [welcomeAlert cancelButtonIndex]) {

        [welcomeAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
        NSLog(@"przycisk 1");

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

       // UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        //SettingsVC *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SVC"];
        //[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];

        //[self showDetailViewController:viewController sender:nil];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settingSegue" sender:nil];


         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving the UIAlertView code from viewDidLoad method to viewDidAppear method ? in viewDidLoad , current view is not yet in hierarchy and when you are displaying alert-view , it might have confusion in view-hierarchy

so

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {

        UIAlertView *welcomeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome!" message:@"This is your first run of Energy Calculator, please select Your default settings first!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"No, thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Go to settings", nil];
        [welcomeAlert show];

        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
    }
}
```

Also , try avoiding UIAlertView , because its deprecated in iOS8+ , use some compatible views to still support iOS 7 , for example https://github.com/ogres/CUIAlertController

and you could easily do the whole process without delegate callbacks :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {

            NSMutableArray *actions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [actions addObject:[CUIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Go to settings" block:^{
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                SettingsVC *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SVC"];
                [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil]
            }]];        

            [actions addObject:[CUIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks" block:nil]];


            [CUIAlertController presentAlertViewWithTitle:@"Welcome!"
                                                  message:@"This is your first run of Energy Calculator, please select Your default settings first!" 
                                                  actions:actions
                                           fromController:self
                                                 animated:YES];

            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
    }
}
```